# Pythonic (Performant) way to mark parent child based on interval

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 12], [4, 9], [6, 7], [10, 11]],
     index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
     columns=['start', 'end'])
     
print(df)
```

Based on the start and end (time interval in Ns), I want to mark the parent child nodes, for example:

```
   start  end parent
A      1   12      A # can be NA
B      4    9      A
C      6    7      B
D     10   11      A
```

For now, I came up with this (`O(N^2)`):

```
df.sort_values(by='start', inplace=True, ascending=False)
df["parent"] = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A']

for row in df.itertuples():
    for ref_row in df.itertuples():
        if (row.start > ref_row.start) & (row.end < ref_row.end):
            df.loc[row.Index, "parent"] = ref_row.Index
            break

df.sort_values(by='start', inplace=True)        
print(df)
```

This works but is clearly inefficient. Please suggest an efficient solution -- maybe using Intervals.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try List comprehension, it is several times faster than a loop and one is enough.

At each iteration, the my_func function is called in which the conditions are checked. Implicit [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) indexing is used, in which the row indexes are on the left, the column number is on the right. If more than one match is obtained, then the first one is taken, through aaa[0].

Note that the row: `C      6    7` matches 'A', 'B'. If nothing is found, the function will return 'A'. Finally, the resulting list is substituted into the 'parent' column.

And in your example the second loop is not needed. In my example, you can remove the `.index` and the result will be filtered rows.

```
df.sort_values(by='start', inplace=True, ascending=False)
df["parent"] = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A']


def my_func(x):
    aaa = df[(df.iloc[x, 0] > df['start']) & (df.iloc[x, 1] < df['end'])].index
    if len(aaa) > 0:
        aaa = aaa[0]#take only the first value if there are several
    else:
        aaa = 'A'#if there is nothing then return 'A'

    return aaa

df['parent'] = [my_func(i) for i in range(len(df))]

df.sort_values(by='start', inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Variant without function.

```
df.sort_values(by='start', inplace=True, ascending=False)

df["parent"] = [df[(df.iloc[i, 0] > df['start']) &
                   (df.iloc[i, 1] < df['end'])].index for i in range(len(df))]


df["parent"] = df['parent'].str[0]
df.fillna(value='A', inplace=True)#fill in 'A' where there were no matches

df.sort_values(by='start', inplace=True)
```

To accurately check the calculation time, put before the calculation:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

and use the following lines at the end:

```
time_ = datetime.datetime.now() - now
print('elapsed time', time_)
```

To accurately check the calculation time, put before the calculation:
and use the following lines at the end:

Comment: For ~5K rows, this solution is approximately 10x faster. Thanks.  @inquirer I will wait for a couple of days to officially accept this answer -- I hope you won't mind.

Comment: No problem. I do not promise, but perhaps I will find a better solution. A question where more than one index turns out the first undertakes or everything is possible(row: C      6    7)? If everything is possible, then you can do without the my_func function.